# New line before a word containg a symbol in notepad ++

Tags: notepad++, line, symbols

I got a text on multiple rows with words that contain ")" symbol. I want to create a new line before every word with ")".

For example I got:

---

```
citrix) 1820193 youtrix) 18337 allow) 29318
gone) 89 lise) 192 top) 192
```

---

And I want to make it like this:

```
citrix) 1820193
youtrix) 18337
allow) 29318
gone) 89
lise) 192
top) 192
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\h+(?=\w+\))`
- Replace with: `\n` or `\r\n` depending on your needs
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\h+         : 1 or more horizontal spaces
(?=         : start lookahead, make sure we have after
    \w+     : 1 or more word character. You may use \S+ if have other characters than word character.
    \)      : a closing parenthesis
)           : end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
\n          : linefeed (you may use \r\n depending on your needs)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
citrix) 1820193
youtrix) 18337
allow) 29318
gone) 89
lise) 192
top) 192
```

Answer (score 0):

Press `Ctrl+H` to open the Replace dialog.

In the `Search Mode`, select `Regular expression`.

In `Find what:`, enter `(\d)\h`.

In `Replace with:`, enter `\1\n`.

Hit `Replace All`.

PS. This will only work if the list are numbers. If you want do this with some non-number lists, you have to enter `([^\)])\h` in the `Find what:`.

Good luck!